Configure Helidon with SSL in http4k
I am trying to configure Helidon Webserver with mutual SSL in http4k.
The following is my configuration
class HelidonSsl(val port: Int = 8305) : ServerConfig {
override val stopMode = ServerConfig.StopMode.Immediate

override fun toServer(http: HttpHandler): Http4kServer {
    val keystorePath = "keystore/ssl.keystore"
    val keystorePassword = "changeit"

    // Set up SSL/TLS configuration if keystore and truststore are present
    val keyStoreKey = Keys.builder()
        .keystore(
            KeystoreKeys.builder()
                .keystore(Resource.create(keystorePath))
                .passphrase(keystorePassword)
                .trustStore(true)
                .build()
        )
        .build()

    val tlsConfig = TlsConfig.builder()
        .trustAll(true)
        .privateKey(keyStoreKey)
        .clientAuth(TlsClientAuth.OPTIONAL)
        .build()

    val server = WebServer.builder()
        .tls(tlsConfig)
        .port(port)
        .build()

    return object : Http4kServer {
        override fun start() = apply { server.start() }
        override fun stop() = apply { server.stop() }
        override fun port(): Int = if (port != 0) port else server.port()
    }
}

The server starts, but when connections are made, I get the following error stack :
I have checked :

keystore  - contains self signed cert usign RSA & password is fine - used the same keystore with Jetty and works fine
different configuration options
debugging shows that the key manager is set to DummyKeyManager instance and this seems to cause the errors but not sure how to fix that



First of all, please include a textual copy of the error instead of a screenshot, this is both less readable, but it also doesn't allow searches for the same issue. As for the problem, it seems you are using the key store with the self signed cert both as key store and trust store. I would try and use two different stores and remove .trustStore(true) from the code.

If this is for Helidon 4, I suggest you start by taking a look at the MTLS example in https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/tree/main/examples/webserver/mutual-tls as a guide. For Helidon 3 it is in https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon-examples/tree/helidon-3.x/examples/webserver/mutual-tls.
